# Is there a benefit for an American to act like a Canadian when traveling internationally?

Tags: usa, canadian-citizens

Some people say that in Greece or Italy, the service at restaurants is better for Canadians.  If I have a backpack with a Canadian patch, would that help me in some countries?

Comment: It might help you in some countries, it will certainly ruin your chances in some countries when found out. Most people do not see you as your president. Nor even as your average countryman. They react on you as you are, if you are a 'Loud Merican' you will get people against you whatever patch you have on your pack.

Comment: To make it convincing, you'd have to keep apologising.

Comment: Consider that if Canadians get better treatment, it may be because of their behavior, and not because of any particular regard for their country. A maple leaf is not a talisman. Be loud like an American or drunk like an Aussie or both like a Brit ;) and all the patch will do is lower opinions of you or of Canadians.

Comment: BTW the `backpack with a Canadian patch` idea is nothing new.  I knew people doing this back in the late 80's.  I'm sure it goes back even further than that.

Comment: A baseball cap with a caption CANADA on it is also required, I suppose.

Comment: I did this when I got tired of people asking me to explain Trump. Then they started asking about Trudeau. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 14):

It depends on what you mean with 'acting like an American' vs. 'acting like a Canadian'.

Americans are (in)famous in Europe for acting as if *they own the world, everybody else lives in a third-world country, and everything should work exactly like it works in the USA, because obviously all other processes are inferior*.

If you are not doing this, you will be fine, and they will welcome you like any visitor. Just act like a *guest*; as you would want guests to act when they visit you.

Comment: What's the difference between God and an American? God knows everything. The American knows everything better.